# File updates twice when dumping pickle

Tags: python, pickle

I have a python script which will run various other scripts when it sees various files have been updated. It rapidly polls the files to check for updates by looking at the file modified dates.

For the most part this has worked as expected. When one of my scripts updates a file, another script is triggered and the appropriate action(s) are taken. For reference I am using pickles as the file type.

However, adding a new file and corresponding script into the mix just now, I've noticed an issue where the file has its modified date updated twice. Once when I perform the pickle.dump() and again when I exit the "with" statement (when the file closes). This means that the corresponding actions trigger twice rather than once. I guess this makes sense but what's confusing is this behaviour doesn't happen with any of my other files.

I know a simple workaround would be to poll the files slightly less frequently since the gap between the file updates is extremely small. But I want to understand why this issue is occuring some times but not other times.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you observe is 2 actions: file created and file updated.
To resolve this, create and populate file outside of monitored folders, and once "with" block is over (file is closed), move it from temporary location to a proper place.

to do this, look at [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) module in standard library

Answer (score 0):

If the pickle is big enough (typically somewhere around 4+ KB, though it will vary by OS/file system), this would be expected behavior. The majority of the pickle would be written during the `dump` call as buffers filled and got written, but whatever fraction doesn't consume the full file buffer would be left in the buffer until the file is closed (which implicitly flushes any outstanding buffered data before closing the handle).

I agree with the other answer that the usual solution is to write the file in a different folder (but on the same file system), then immediately after closing it, us `os.replace` to perform an atomic rename that moves it from the temporary location to the final location, so there is no gap between file open, file population, and file close; the file is either there in its entirety, or not at all.

Comment: Using os.replace "immediately" after exiting the "with" block (and thus closing the file) didn't resolve the issue. However, sleeping for 1 second before performing os.replace worked as expected. I don't understand why this is the case given the explanation of the issue.

Comment: @SockPastaRock: You might want to explicitly `os.sync()` after the `with` block to ensure all changes to file data/metadata are fully written; it shouldn't be necessary (anything else opening the file should see the file as complete thanks to the OS serving as intermediary, even if the data isn't fully written), but it does guarantee the file is *really* there.